# Is it possible to browse the internet from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

For example, is something like `wget` available in Windows XP?

Comment: There are countless Internet tools for DOS, but your question is very unclear. You ask about _browsing_ the Internet (which implies a web browser), then you talk about wget, which is incapable of browsing.  Please clarify your question as to exactly _which_ types of tools you want for DOS.

Comment: you still haven't upgraded from DOS ;)?

Comment: I really don't understand why people downvote, why people downvote a question like this one.

Comment: @ doob, i just want to know about it. Though i'm planning to upgrade to Windows 3.2 :P

Answer (score 6):

if its dos proper (windows command line is NOT called dos - its the cmd shell), you can use [Arachnae](http://www.glennmcc.org/arachne/), else emgee's suggestion of lynx sounds like a good bet.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a built in solution, use

```
telnet www.superuser.com 80
```

and type in raw HTTP commands.

If you need a browser, then maybe you can use cygwin and a text mode browser like lynx (there's [a site dedicated](http://pachome1.pacific.net.sg/~kennethkwok/lynx/) to a windows port).

If you need a real DOS Browser (16-Bit), there may be some as well, haven't looked.

Comment: i tried these but it did not worked [does not show any content]

Answer (score 4):

if you want pure dos version

- try the first link on [Doug Kaufman's Web Site - DOS ports](http://www.rahul.net/dkaufman/)
- or try to find any download for [Arachne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachne_%28web_browser%29)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want a win32 compatible text-based browser?

You can try a win32 version of Lynx -> http://pachome1.pacific.net.sg/~kennethkwok/lynx/index.html